# How to Unit Test an MVC Controller with Three Dependencies, Using Moq

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd, moq

Caveat: I'm brand spanking new to Moq, Unit Testing with Moq, and TDD, generally.

I have a controller with three dependencies. Here is the Constructor (etc) to the SomethingController:

```
public class SomethingController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<SomethingController> _logger;
        private readonly ISomethingRepository _something;
        private readonly IExceptionSvc _ex;

        public SomethingController(ILogger<SomethingController> logger,
            ISomethingRepository something,
            IExceptionSvc ex)
        {            
            _logger = logger;
            _something = something;
            _ex = ex;

        }

[HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public JsonResult GetStuff()
        {
            //intitialize list
            var stuffs = new List<StuffViewModel>();

        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("SomethingController: GetStuff() - Getting Stuff, sorted ascending.");

            //get the stuffs
            stuffs = _something.GetStuff();

            _logger.LogInformation("Retrieved {0} Stuffs.", stuffs.Count);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Error in SomethingController: GetStuff()", ex);
            return _ex.Http500ErrorReturn("GetStuff");
        }

        return Json(stuffs);
    }

}
```

Now, here is the description of what each dependency is for:

**ILogger**: This is simply for logging, using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging via NLog. 
**ISomethingRepository**: This does all the work (well...the impementation of it, really). It calls the database and gets things. There is a method called **GetStuff()**, which simply returns a list of Stuffs. This Repository has a dependency on the database, which is injected into the repo via the constructor.

**IExceptionSvc**: This is just a dumb little service that has a method that returns a 500 Error response for a JSON formatted return to the caller.

I want to test the GetStuff() action in the Controller, which will call the GetStuff() implementation in the Repository.

I currently have the following code stubbed in, in my test project:

```
public void GetStuff_Is_Awesome()
        {
            Mock<ILogger<SomethingController>> logger = new Mock<ILogger<SomethingController>>();
            Mock<ISomethingRepository> something = new Mock<ISomethingRepository>();
            Mock <IExceptionSvc> ex = new Mock<IExceptionSvc>();
            SomethingController sc = new SomethingController(logger.Object, something.Object, ex.Object);

sc.GetStuff();

//...what now? What am I looking for? Am I going to see a list of stuffs here?

}
```

I just want to know what to expect? Am I testing whether a list of Stuffs was returned? How do I test that?

Here is the implementation of GetStuff() in the Repository (with the repo constructor for reference sake):

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger<SomethingRepository> _logger;

        public SomethingRepository(ApplicationDbContext context,
            ILogger<SomethingRepository> logger)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
        }

public List<StuffViewModel> GetStuff()
        {
            List<StuffViewModel> stuffs = null;
            stuffs = _context.Stuffs.OrderBy(b => b.Name).Select(b => new StuffViewModel
                {
                    Id = b.Id,
                    Name = b.Name
                }).ToList();

return stuffs;
            }
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: I added the GetStuff() implementation now.

Comment: Assuming `GetStuff` is an action, then the return will be an `ActionResult`. You would then need to inspect that return value to assert various things you want to test about it.

Comment: @crackedcornjimmy You would want to show the `SomethingController.GetStuff` action method. That way it is known how the method under test interacts with the dependencies.

Comment: I added SomethingController.GetStuff now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of it as Arrange, Act Assert

```
public void GetStuff_Is_Awesome()
{
    //arrange
    Mock<ILogger<SomethingController>> logger = new Mock<ILogger<SomethingController>>();
    Mock<ISomethingRepository> something = new Mock<ISomethingRepository>();
    Mock <IExceptionSvc> ex = new Mock<IExceptionSvc>();
    SomethingController sc = new SomethingController(logger.Object, something.Object, ex.Object);

    //act
    sc.GetStuff();

    //assert
}
```

So, you want to *assert* that something happened, or something was called.

Without knowing more about your domain, or the ISomethingRepository, you *could* Assert that the method was called:

```
something.Verify(m => m.MethodToCheckIfCalled());
```

Other options would be to setup the return values for `MethodToCheckIfCalled` and assert the results etc...

Assuming a `GetStuff` method on your controller that looks like:

```
public ActionResult GetStuff()
{
    var data = _something.GetFromRepo();
    return View(data);
}
```

I would do something like:

```
public void GetStuff_Is_Awesome() //please don't call it this
{
    //arrange
    Mock<ILogger<SomethingController>> logger = new Mock<ILogger<SomethingController>>();
    Mock<ISomethingRepository> something = new Mock<ISomethingRepository>();
    Mock <IExceptionSvc> ex = new Mock<IExceptionSvc>();
    SomethingController sc = new SomethingController(logger.Object, something.Object, ex.Object);

    //setup your something mock GetFromRepo method to return a List of StuffViewModel
    something.Setup(m=> m.GetFromRepo())
        .Returns(new List<StuffViewModel>(){Id = 1, Name = "Test"});

    //act
    var result = sc.GetStuff();

    //assert

    //safely cast result to ViewResult
    var viewResult = result as ViewResult;

    Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult);
    Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult.Model); 

    // add additional checks on the Model.. loads of ways of doing this
    var viewResultModel = viewResut.Model as List<StuffViewModel>;

    Assert.AreEqual(1, viewResultModel.First().Id);
    Assert.AreEqual("Test", viewResultModel.First().Name);
}
```

Comment: I added an implementation of GetStuff(). Does that help with specificity?

Comment: I did something like your answer and am seeing a bit of light here. The one item that is getting to me, though, is that the test doesn't actually hit the database. Thus, no data ever gets returned. Is this expected?

Comment: @crackedcornjimmy that is expected. If you want to hit the database then use the actual implementation, but then it becomes an integration test not a unit test in isolation.

Comment: @Nkosi, can you give an example of both types in an answer?

Comment: "that the test doesn't actually hit the database" - that's the point of the mocking framework - to mock your database. That's what you use `Setup` to setup your mock object to return the data as if it were to hit the database.

Comment: @crackedcornjimmy more than enough documentation online https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/unit-testing/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-applications-cs